# Changing HTML with jQuery, below the script

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know if it possible to change HTML with jQuery that appears below the script?

I'm using:
    `$("div.className").html("My changed HTML here");`
to change some text on a page. However it seems to only work if that HTML appears somewhere above the script placement. Is it possible to have it work on HTML that appears below the script placement? Or does the script need to be the last thing to load on the page?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As a general best practice, placing `<script>` tags at the very bottom of the page is the way to go. [http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your jQuery-enabled code into a `$(document).ready()` block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.className").html("My changed HTML here");
});
```

Your code wasn't working because you were looking for an element that hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Ah Ha! Thanks everyone for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

put in ready function.Then it will work.Like

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.className").html("My changed HTML here");
});
```